# MVC combobox and how to save it in database?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I am a beginner in MVC (but not in C#), but the project must be made in Visual Studio .NET app (MVC or WPF) using Entity Framework. I made a Database First app, but here is my problem:

In table Customers
I have Id, Title, Name, MiddleName, Surname, Address, CountryId(relationship to Table Countries[Id, Name] 1 to many), Active(bit, True/False, Checkbox)

In table Countries
Id, Name(predefined)

Another table Titles(that I made, because I couldn't hardcode dropdownlists)
Id, TitleName

My question is when I created the Controller + View, the Title is displayed as TextBox(aka @Html.Editor(...)), when I change it to `@Html.DropDownList("nameHere", null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`

Then in my GET I create a dropdown view list:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
           ViewBag.nameHere = new SelectList(db.Titles, "Id", "TitleName");
            ViewBag.CountryId = new SelectList(db.Countries, "Id", "Name");
            return View();
        }
```

Then in my POST I put it too:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Name,MiddleName,Surname,Address,CountryId,Active")] Customer customer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Customers.Add(customer);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.nameHere = new SelectList(db.Titles, "Id", "TitleName", db.Title); //selects from table Titles the Id and TitleName for the field Title in Customers table? at least that's how I interpretate it
            ViewBag.CountryId = new SelectList(db.Countries, "Id", "Name", customer.CountryId); //same for Country
            return View(customer);
        }
```

But I have 3 problems:

1st one - the server returns for Title in db.Customers NULL value
2nd one - if I don't use dropdown then it will send the value from the TextBox field(but people can write whatever they want)
3rd one(when using ViewBag and ViewData) - There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key "nameHere"

I just want a simple dropdown list where I have 4 options - Ms, Mrs, Mr, Miss and when I select it and send the full form to the server(Name, MiddleName, Surname, etc), in the table Customers to save the string from the dropdown list. nothing more.

I made my db with Database First(aka creating db then Model, not around)

Comment: ask one question per post, don't ask bunch of questions

Comment: I am asking how to make the dropdown list option in View(lets say it displays "Mr.") to be saved in my db in Title(type string). It sends a null value!

Comment: how are you reading it in post action, show that particular code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/h8e6Ag74 this is how I post it. It sends a null value back and since in database it cannot be null it shows db.SaveChanges(); error, I used diagnostics and breakpoint and it pointed towards the Title dropdown list that it cannot find ViewData/or it's of System.String, but there is no IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with an answer with some OOP:

```
Inside the controller(GET method):
List<string> ListItems = new List<string>();
            ListItems.Add("Ms.");
            ListItems.Add("Mrs.");
            ListItems.Add("Mr.");
            ListItems.Add("Miss");
            SelectList Titles = new SelectList(ListItems);
            ViewData["Titles"] = Titles;
```

Inside the View:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Title", ViewData["Titles"] as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```